# Calculating chmod based on user input

Tags: python, python-2.x, calculator

This program asks the user for input three times, and based on that input, calculates the chmod. I have included comments with questions and clarifications in the code.

I would like to have these questions answered and help with making the `if ... in ...` part shorter, if that's possible.

```
'''
This program asks the user for input three times, and based on that input, calculates the chmod.
'''

'''
This is a simple function that prevents me from repeating myself.
Usage:
    whoCan('execute')
will return 'Who can execute?'
'''

def whoCan(doThis):
    '''
    If I use `print` instead of `return` here, this is the output:

     Who can read?
     None

    Why is that?
    '''
    return "Who can %s?" % doThis

'''
Ask the user for input in the form of 'ow', 'gr' and 'ot'.
FYI:
    ow = owner
    gr = group
    ot = other

chmod 777 would be  owgrot
                    owgrot
                    owgrot
'''

read = raw_input(whoCan('read'))
write = raw_input(whoCan('write'))
execute = raw_input(whoCan('execute'))

'''
I didn't have any success with
    readValue, writeValue, executeValue = int()
Why?
'''

readValue = 0
writeValue = 0
executeValue = 0

# There must be a shorter way to write this...

if 'ow' in read:
    readValue += 4
if 'gr' in read:
    readValue += 2
if 'ot' in read:
    readValue += 1

if 'ow' in write:
    writeValue += 4
if 'gr' in write:
    writeValue += 2
if 'ot' in write:
    writeValue += 1

if 'ow' in execute:
    executeValue += 4
if 'gr' in execute:
    executeValue += 2
if 'ot' in execute:
    executeValue += 1

# And print the chmod

print readValue, writeValue, executeValue
```

Comment: If you answer "Who can read?" `ow`, "Who can write?" `ow`, "Who can execute?" `ow`, then the answer should be `700`, but you actually print `4 4 4`.

Comment: I think this link with an interactive calculator may help you understand it better http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html

Answer (score 0):

#### Concise coding

After moving the documentation of the function after the line containing `def` as the convention stands we have:

```
def whoCan(doThis):
    '''
    This is a simple function that prevents me from repeating myself.
    Usage:
        whoCan('execute')
    will return 'Who can execute?'

    If I use `print` instead of `return` here, this is the output:

     Who can read?
     None

    Why is that?
    '''
    return "Who can %s?" % doThis
```

The second paragraph is just a doubt that is not really relevant to this function (the reason is that: using `print` creates a function with no return of which the return is implicitly `None`, that is printed by `raw_input`), so we can remove it:

```
def whoCan(doThis):
    '''
    This is a simple function that prevents me from repeating myself.
    Usage:
        whoCan('execute')
    will return 'Who can execute?'
    '''
    return "Who can %s?" % doThis
```

I can already see that it is a (simple) function, and functions are usually used to avoid repetition so we can remove it too:

```
def whoCan(doThis):
    '''
    Usage:
        whoCan('execute')
    will return 'Who can execute?'
    '''
    return "Who can %s?" % doThis
```

In fact we may remove this whole function as it is just doing `"Who can {}?".format(action)` where x is the input.

To avoid repetition we will use a generator expression:

```
read, write, execute = (raw_input("Who can {}?".format(action)) for action in ('read', 'write', 'execute'))
```

The last part can be shortened with a dictionary and a function that calls `sum` on a generator expression:

```
name_to_val = {'ow' : 4, 'gr' : 2, 'ot' : 1}

def chmod_value(x):
    return sum(name_to_val(name) for name in name_to_val.keys() if name in x)
```

You also do not need to initialize variables with zero, in fact you do not need variables at all:

```
print [chmod_value(x) for x in (read, write, execute)]
```

Comment: Iterating a dictionary goes through its keys.  Using `.keys()` in the generator expression is redundant.